# Create many network adapters and force different programs use different adapters

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-adapter

I have a Windows 7 PC with one Internet connection through one physical network adapter. I'm running many copies of different network programs. As a result, all the programs are using the same network adapter with the same settings.

I'm after the ability to set up different adapter settings for each program.

I was thinking about creating different virtual adapters and then, somehow, binding each program to the different adapters.

The main problem is, everything should work automatically, without manually setting anything each time the program is started.

For example, when 1.exe is started (by me or by another program) it should connect to the Internet through adapter1, when 2.exe is started it should use adapter2, and so on.

Basically, I have two questions.

1) How do I create 10+ network adapters?

2) How do I bind the different programs to different adapters?

Answer (score 1):

You can create 10+ network adapters by adding virtual network adapter.
A virtual network adapter is a program (instead of a physical network adapter) that allows a computer to connect to a network. A virtual network adapter can also be used to connect all the computers on a local area network (LAN) to a larger network such as the Internet or a collection of LANs.
Following is a link about how to create virtual network adapter, it may be helpful to you.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s4PrqOfJRgs

You can bind different programs to different adapters through a  tool **ForceBindIP**.
ForceBindIP is a command line application without a friendly graphical user interface that allows you to easily bind a selected application with an IP or network adapter. 
Read More: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/bind-windows-application-to-specific-network-adapter-with-forcebindip/